# Enforce calling one closure before another

Tags: rust, closures, trait-bounds

I want to bundle two closures together in a struct. One closure is there to test if the inputs are valid, and the other closure is to actually do the stuff. Here is one variation that works:

```rust
struct Foo<T, F>
{
    test: T,
    func: F,
}

fn make_foo<A, B, T, F>(test: T, func: F) -> Foo<T, F>
where
    T: Fn(A) -> bool,
    F: Fn(A) -> B
{
    Foo {
        test,
        func,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = make_foo(|a: i32| {a > 5}, |a: i32| { a + 8 });
    if (foo.test)(10) {
        println!("{}", (foo.func)(10));
    }
    else {
        println!("Input too small");
    }
}
```

However, Rust being Rust, there are a few issues that seem non-idiomatic. In particular, there is no check to see if `test` was actually run, and there is no enforcing that `test` and `func` are run with the same arguments.

So, I set out to try to fix that. My idea is that `foo.test` returns an `Option<Fn>`, where the `Some` variant contains `func`, but with the input I want to use already fed to it. So something like this as a first draft:

```rust
struct Foo<T>
{
    test: T
}

fn make_foo<A, B, T, F, H>(t: T, f: F) -> Foo<H>
where
    T: Fn(A) -> bool,
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
    H: Fn(A) -> Option<Fn() -> B>,
{
    Foo {
        test: |a: A| {
            if t(a) {
                Some(| | {f(a)})
            }
            else {
                None
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = make_foo(|a: i32| {a > 5}, |a: i32| { a + 8 });
    if let Some(f) = (foo.test)(10) {
        println!("{}", f());
    }
    else {
        println!("Input too small");
    }
}
```

This complains that `Fn() -> B` needs `dyn`, which of course also means it has unknown size at compile time. So we `Box` it:

```rust
fn make_foo<A, B, T, F, H>(t: T, f: F) -> Foo<H>
where
    T: Fn(A) -> bool,
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
    H: Fn(A) -> Option<Box<dyn Fn() -> B>>,
{
    Foo {
        test: |a: A| {
            if t(a) {
                Some(Box::new(| | {f(a)}))
            }
            else {
                None
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it complains that it `expected type parameter` H`, found closure` on the closure that I have written here, and I don't really know what that means. It also complains that it now wants an explicit type signature on `foo` inside `main`, and given that that type includes closures, I don't think that I can even do that. Also, I haven't even gotten to touch the `a` parameter yet. Presumably I need a `move` in there.

Have I dug myself into a hole here that I cannot get out of, or is there some decent way to solve this? Or is there a more ergonomic way to solve the two issues I had with my functioning code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [existential type instead of an universal one](/questions/47929824/what-makes-impl-trait-as-an-argument-universal-and-as-a-return-value-existe):

```rust
fn make_foo<A, B, T, F>(t: T, f: F) -> Foo<impl Fn(A) -> Option<Box<dyn Fn() -> B>>>
where
    A: Copy + 'static,
    T: Fn(A) -> bool,
    F: Fn(A) -> B + Copy + 'static,
{
    Foo {
        test: move |a: A| {
            if t(a) {
                Some(Box::new(move || {f(a)}) as _)
            }
            else {
                None
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A type parameter always means that the caller can choose a type for it, but you can't provide an arbitrary `Fn(A) -> Option<Box<dyn Fn() -> B>>` you only can provide a single specific value of that sort, your closure.

Comment: You mean [something like this playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9e3526412cec5abc25ff261e73336802)? I might have made some subtle typo, but I can't get it to work. The complaint is basically the same, except it doesn't refer to `H`.

Comment: Ah yes you have to cast the `Box`, then because of moved variables you have to add additional constraints to your parameters, I've added what the compiler suggested but your actual requirements might vary.

Comment: I have types with strings in them, so `Copy` is out of the question. But I managed to make it work with `Clone` instead, [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8c0c3ef1ceb14a981e0502dd2fb3dfc), basically by adding a line cloning the `a` and giving one of the clones to `t` and the other to `f` inside the boxed closure, and adding `Option<Box<dyn FnOnce() -> B>>`. I don't know yet exactly what my actual lifetime constraints are, we will see when I implement this into my actual code. But for the moment, this looks very promising. Thank you for the help.